# How to get the file location of a class?

Tags: ruby

I want to design a class as below:

```
class A

    @@instances ||= []

    attr_reader :path, :name

    def initialize name
       @name = name
       @path = # I don't know how to get the path of instance.
       @@instances << self
    end

    def self.show_all_instances
        puts @@instances.collect {|i| "Name: #{i.name}, Path： #{i.path}"} .join('\n')
    end
end
```

Then I will create many instances under different folders.

```
folder1/foo.rb
A.new 'foo'
folder2/bar.rb
A.new 'bar'
...
```

I expect result as below

```
A.show_all_instances
```

outputs:

```
   Name: foo, Path: folder1/foo.rb
   Name: bar, Path: folder2/bar.rb
```

...

So how do I know where the calling class is, to enter the path?

Sorry, I don't explain my question very well. I want to get the ruby file path where the instances created...

Comment: Hey, what do you meen by 'instances under different folders'? Are you sure you understand what a Ruby object instance is?

Comment: How are you running the different files? As long as these files are all included/required by a single file, or one of them includes/requires the others, they should work as you expected.

Comment: Sorry, I don't explain my question very well. I want to get the ruby file path where the instances created...

Comment: What do you mean by path? An instance of a class doesn't have a path as far as a location on disk. A Ruby script that contains the code that was run to define the class or create the instance has a path on disk, and is available via `__FILE__`. The running Ruby script has a path, and is available via `$0`.

Comment: @theTinMan: I figure she means the path of the file where the code that instantiates the instance is located.

Comment: That seems contradicted by the OPs comment to @ChanceDoor's answer, `FILE can't meet what I want. If I define class A in a.rb, the path of instance will always be a.rb. I want the path is where the instance defined...`. I think the question is incomplete and the OP doesn't really know what is wanted.

Comment: @theTinMan I think that says in broken English what boris stated. `where _instance_ defined` should probably have been `where instance is instantiated` otherwise the statement is an oxymoron

Comment: @RuneFS sorry for my poor English. I figure out how to resolve this problem now. When I want to use a instance in other file, I need to require 'file path', then I could set path, like A.instances.last.path = 'file path'... it's a scenario within my actual code... anyway, thanks for all your kindly help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#a.rb
def initialize name,path
   @name = name
   @path = path
   @@instances << self
end

#foo.rb
a = A.new 'foo',__FILE__ #or File.expand_path __FILE__
```

Comment: __FILE__ can't meet what I want. If I define class A in a.rb, the path of instance will always be a.rb. I want the path is where the instance defined...

Comment: @ChanceDoor yes, I should pass the path when I require the other rb files. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you mean by "instances under folders". Under the assumptions that it's the file where the instance is "made", and the filename is always "instance_name.rb", and using `gem install y_support` to handle the mundane chores of object naming and instance management, the solution is:

```
require 'y_support/name_magic'
class A
  include NameMagic
  attr_reader :path
  def initialize
    @path = File.dirname( File.expand_path __FILE__ )
  end
  def inspect
    "Name: '#{name}', path '#{path}/#{name.to_s.downcase}.rb'"
  end
end

# Now in folder1
Foo = A.new
# and in folder2
Bar = A.new
# Then:
A.instances
#=> [Name: 'Foo', path 'folder1/foo.rb', Name: 'Bar', path 'folder2/bar.rb']
```